# Fail handling SIGINT in hierarchical process execution

Tags: bash, signals

I have the following process execution structure:

```
script0.sh
    script1.sh
        script2.sh
        script3.sh
```

Meaning:

- script0.sh executes script1.sh.
- script1.sh executes script2.sh and script3.sh.

Ideally, I want to have a single trap handler in script1.sh, which would perform a cleanup and exit.
For some reason, it doesn't work.

I also tried having a trap handlers in all my scripts, but only the trap handler in script0.sh is being called.

I tried using the trap handler in script0.sh to kill the child process (i.e. script1.sh) but the process hangs until it completes.

I used the command 'trap -p' and noticed that only script0.sh has trap handlers, although that I registered trap handlers for all the scripts.

Note:

- script2.sh is actually 'rsync', the remaining scripts are my own.
- script1.sh, script2.sh and script3.sh were sent to background using '&' operator.
- I perform 'wait' for every process that is sent to background.

---

I created the script files which reproduce this issue:

script0.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function cleanup_script0()
{
    echo "SIGINT in script0.sh"
    kill -s SIGINT $script1_pid
    wait $script1_pid
}

trap cleanup_script0 SIGINT

./script1.sh &
script1_pid=$!
wait $script1_pid
```

script1.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function cleanup_script1()
{
    echo "SIGINT in script1.sh"
    kill -s SIGINT $script2_pid
    wait $script2_pid
    kill -s SIGINT $script3_pid
    wait $script3_pid
}

trap cleanup_script1 SIGINT

rsync_file_to_copy="$( mktemp )"
dd if=/dev/urandom of="$rsync_file_to_copy" bs=1M count=1
rsync --timeout=5 --bwlimit=200 "$rsync_file_to_copy" "$( mktemp -d )/" &
script2_pid=$!
wait $script2_pid
echo "Finished script2.sh"

./script3.sh
script3_pid=$!
wait $script3_pid
echo "Finished script3.sh"
```

script3.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function cleanup_script3()
{
    echo "SIGINT in script3.sh"
}

trap cleanup_script3 SIGINT

delay_counter=0
while [ 8 -gt $delay_counter ]; do
    echo "script3.sh: $( date "+%H_%M_%S" )"
    let 'delay_counter++'
    sleep 1
done
```

---

The output for execution of the above scripts is as follows:

The output for when CTRL+C during rsync:

```
$ ./script0.sh 
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.00604244 s, 174 MB/s
^CSIGINT in script0.sh
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(703) [sender=3.2.3]
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at io.c(503) [generator=3.2.3]
Finished script2.sh
script3.sh: 23_57_24
script3.sh: 23_57_25
script3.sh: 23_57_26
script3.sh: 23_57_27
script3.sh: 23_57_28
script3.sh: 23_57_29
script3.sh: 23_57_30
script3.sh: 23_57_31
Finished script3.sh
```

The output for when CTRL+C during script3.sh:

```
$ ./script0.sh 
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.00585018 s, 179 MB/s
Finished script2.sh
script3.sh: 23_57_46
script3.sh: 23_57_47
^CSIGINT in script0.sh
script3.sh: 23_57_48
script3.sh: 23_57_49
script3.sh: 23_57_50
script3.sh: 23_57_51
script3.sh: 23_57_52
script3.sh: 23_57_53
Finished script3.sh
```

Comment: is `script1` doing anything else? because otherwise the `rsync ... & wait;` could be replaced with the simpler `rsync ...;`

Comment: @thrig currently script1.sh doesn't do something else. But I prefer to leave it like this. Anyway the same issue exist

Comment: Important conclusion: Regarding `script0.sh`: If I write `./script1.sh` instead of `./script1.sh &` then script1.sh is able to detect SIGINT such that its handler is executed. Therefore, I conclude that the SIGINT handling was passed to it because it is part of the "foreground" execution.

Comment: In my script1.sh file I also had an additional issue which was caused by redirection with `exec`, like so: `exec > >(tee "${script_log_filepath}") 2>&1`. This caused the SIGINT to be ignored for script1.sh, so instead of the handler, the script would just exit. That can be solved with pipes (`mkfifo`) instead of process substitution.

Answer (score 2):

A <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will result in a SIGINT sent to
every member of the foreground process group (or no signal at all; see
the `termios` man page). Thus, we can simplify the signal handling by
relying on the usual behavior of a signal to the process group, even
as more and more changes come to light as to what the scripts are
actually doing.

```
#!/bin/sh
# script0 - apparently this script does more things that were absent
# in the question, so we run the first script instead of executing
# the next script (this changes nothing from the prior result)
./script1
echo and we do some other things here ...
```

and `script1`, which now apparently has some sort of output redirection
going on, somewhere it it, so let's guess that happened up at the top
(this changes nothing from the prior result):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# script1 - replace rsync with a hopefully similar `sleep` call,
# plus now the output redirect, minus anything they haven't yet
# told us about

exec > >(tee and-a-ruthless-devotion-to-the-pope) 2>&1

echo RUN script2
# `command & wait;` is just a complicated and verbose way to write
# `command;` (unless there is yet another thing going on they
# haven't yet told us about??)
sleep 9

echo RUN script3
./script3
```

and `script3`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
delay_counter=0
while [[ 8 -gt $delay_counter ]]; do
   echo -n "script3 time "
   date +%H:%M:%S
   (( delay_counter++ ))
   sleep 1
done
```

which after `chmod +x script*` still again results in

```
$ ./script0
RUN script2
^C
$ ./script0
RUN script2
RUN script3
script3 time 16:28:31
script3 time 16:28:32
script3 time 16:28:33
^C
$
```

Needless signal handling only complicates matters, and requires even
more complications to try to workaround the resulting complications. Why
not simplify and rely on the default behavior?

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort though this solution limits my capabilities because that `exec` doesn't execute the remaining script.
I noticed through file `/proc/$$/status` that the signal SIGINT is ignored (field `SigIgn` in the file). So I tried with SIGTERM and it worked well. I think, maybe it is a feature, because that only one process is supposed to handle user interruption (SIGINT), such that the other processes should respond to SIGTERM accordingly

Comment: "only one process is supposed to handle SIGINT" is a false claim. The signal is sent to each and every process in the foreground process group, as is documented, and can be observed with suitable tracing of processes.

Comment: probably, though this is my interpretation of what I observed. These processes are in background, so it makes sense with what you wrote, no?